# Защита от DDoS, при помощи php

Tags: ddos, php

Здравствуйте, хотел узнать. Есть ли польза, от того если написать php скрипт который будет банить ip адреса с которых, идёт большое количество запросов (DDoS). Например:

```
// php код
if (!ipbanned($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
rememberQuery($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // Функция, которая запоминает ip адрес пользователя выполнившего запрос
$q = getLastQueryTime($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // Функция, которая возвращает время(метку) последнего запроса, с данного ip, или если пользователь с данным ip не посылал запрос, то false;
// Если последний запрос выполнен меньше секунды, то баним ip адрес
if ($q && (time()-$q) < 1)
{
banIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // Функция, которая банит указанный ip адрес
}
else
die("С вашего IP адреса, слишком часто посылаются запросы. Ваш  IP адрес заблокирован.");
```

Т.е если слишком часто запросов, то система банит его... список последних посещений и забаненых адресов, непосредственно храним в кэшэ... Такой вариант как-то поможет, или я несу вам бред товарищи?

P.S. Код написал на коленке, возможны какие-либо недочёты, это я так для демонстрации.

P.P.S. Если ещё при обнаружении атаки, скрипт будет сам собирать себя в gz архив, и сливаться база в sql файл, всё это через cron, и высылаться на емеил админа, думаю это будет хорошо? Хотя если емеил админа сломают, то горе ему...

Comment: Не думаю что найдутся такие орлы, кто будет с кнопкой F5 в браузере играться... xD

Comment: @Maalik, тут ещё надо смотреть от какого типа DoS'а вы хотите защититься. Если от флуда, то скорее всего Вам хватит проверки на корректность параметров. А вообще, судя по вашему коду - вы наоборот привлекаете атаку второго рода( атака, которая стремится вызвать ложное срабатывание системы защиты и таким образом привести к недоступности ресурса - ВИКИ). Не уверен про запрос меньше секунды. На чём основано Ваше предположение о том, что тот, кто выполняет несколько запросов в секунду есть потенциальный хацкер?

Comment: @Maalik, к тому же моё мнение таково, что интерпритатором вы скорее всего не защитите. Смотрите в сторону сервера

Answer (score 4):

Я бы вам порекомендовал узнать чуть больше о DDos`е. Дальше.. Запомните раз и навсегда, делайте сайты так, что бы не бояться рефрешей, большого числа запросов в секунду.

Типичный пример: Я набрел на вашговносайт и умудрился найти что то интересное, скопировал ссылку и кинул в рабочий чатик. Все 30 контактов умудряются открыть сайт в одну секунду и что мы видим? Правильно! Упоротый разработчик закрыл сайт от пользователей, так как ИП в конторе один на 30 человек.

Защиты от ДДос атак нужно делать на уровне сетевого интерфейса (поправьте кто-нибудь, если я не так это назвал), методом настройки IPTABLES.

Comment: Верно говоришь товарищ. На уровне сетевого интерфейса надо делать.

Answer (score 1):

Как специалист в данной сфере, я не мог пройти мимо вопроса.

Для начала, обозначу, что DDoS атаки бывают на разном уровне - это может быть сетевой уровень или уровень приложения. В случае атак сетевого уровня - атаку нужно блокировать, если возможно, до сервера - на роутере провайдера/хостера. Если это невозможно - необходимо воспользоваться Iptables, которым отфильтровать невалидный TCP трафик. UDP же трафик в таких случаях лучше полностью ограничить в вашу сторону, попросив об этом провайдера.
Так как суть DDoS атаки - исчерпание ресурсов вашего сервера, то математика очень простая - производительность/каналы вашего сервера должны позволять справиться с ней, чудес увы не бывает.

Немного иначе обстоит дело с атаками на уровне приложения, кажется это именно то, о чем вы спрашивали. Самый простой пример - использование функции поиска или любой другой тяжелой функции, которая способна нагрузить базу данных. Соответственно, нападающий в несколько потоков генерирует запросы к тяжелой функции и приложение замедляется или не работает. С простыми атаками такого толка действительно можно справиться правильной настройкой вебсервера - nginx/apache, разумными приемами оптимизации производительности системы - кеши, оптимизация базы etc. Об этом много информации в сети, уверен, без труда найдете достойные рекомендации.

На практике, для блокировки большинства простых атакующих ботов вам достаточно реализовать проверку js и куки, если "посетитель" не умеет этого - значит забанить, иначе пропустить.

Comment: Вы имеете какое-то отношение к https://esteq.net? Если да, [отметьте это в ответе явно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 0):

DDOSом должен заниматься системный администратор а не программист

Comment: В идеале да. Но как правило это ложиться на плечи разработчика.

Comment: у нас всегда через "эти плечи" делается )

Answer (score 0):

Защиту от Ddos атаки нужно делать на уровне веб-сервера.

Пример настройки такой защиты можете найти по [ссылке](http://habrahabr.ru/post/247391/) . Существует много способов, как платные так и бесплатные. Самый эффективные это платные сервисы, по сути Вы через их сервера пропускаете траффик, они его фильтруют на предмет флуда и уже отфильтрованный трафик попадает к Вам [например](https://stormwall.pro/)

Comment: А так же утечка информации и т.п.. как бесплатный бонус к платной услуге ?

Comment: Советую Вам прочитать как работаю данные услуги. Суть такова, что при первом входе на сайте (открыли страничку) пусть проходит через сервера того кто предоставил услугу, если с траффиком все ок то все остальные данные напрямую пересылаются от клиента до сайта. Никакой утечки информации

Comment: Уж простите не вижу в этих платных услугах смысла и пользы вообще.

Comment: Каждый сам для себя выбирает что ему использовать, кому-то подходит решение сделанное свои руками или бесплатное. Кому то нужно коммерческое решение. Я всего лишь предложил варианты платные и бесплатные. Каждый сам для себя выбирает

Answer (score 0):

Делать защиту от DDoS при помощи PHP не совсем корректно.
Во первых это медленно. 
Во вторых делать это надо средставами веб сервера.

Если сделать это средствами сервера невозможно по каким либо причинам, то на PHP можно организовать разве что блок по IP но только не автоматический, а в ручном режиме (в качестве вспомогательного инструмента можно добавить еще статистику: с какого IP сколько обращений было в разрезе по часам).

Тогда не будет случайной блокировки пользователей с одного IP, а блокировать вы сможете тогда, когда сайт будет реально тормозить из-за DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, у меня есть ботнет из миллиарда wi-fi чайников. Я отдаю команду этим чайникам в одну и ту же секунду выполнить затратное по ресурсом действие на сайте, например, поиск. Вы получите миллиард внешних адресов. Ваша проверка на DDOS только увеличит нагрузку на сервер. 
PHP не стоит использовать для защиты от DDOS.